# How to call default ServerCertificateValidationCallback inside customized validation?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate

I want to modify .Net's default `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to validate as true some of my company's certificates, but keeping the default validation for other certificates.

I can't seem to do this since the default `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` value is null.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
 validCertificatesSerialNumbers.Contains(certificate.GetSerialNumberString()) ||    
 defaultlCallback.Invoke(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) //How do I set defaultCallback?
;
```

Thank you

Comment: From what I can tell, [the validation has already been done](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/ServicePoint.cs,1036) and all that is needed is to check that `sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None`.

Comment: Cool, would you set it as an answer?

Comment: Aside: Using Thumbprint rather than SerialNumber is a safer way to do this. Serial number is specified at creation time, and the serial number is public to anyone who can view  the certificate, so it's trivial to create a self-signed certificate that has a specific serial. Thumbprint is a cryptographic hash of the key, so while theoretically finding a collision isn't impossible, it's computationally too expensive to actually do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I can tell in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/ServicePoint.cs,1036) this is where the callback comes into play:

```
if (ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback != null)
{
    useDefault = false;
    return ServicePointManager.ServerCertValidationCallback.
                               Invoke(m_Request,
                                      certificate,
                                      chain,
                                      sslPolicyErrors);
}

if (useDefault)
    return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
```

Which means that the validation has already been performed and to know whether it passes you just need to check the `sslPolicyErrors` argument. You would do this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
validCertificatesSerialNumbers.Contains(certificate.GetSerialNumberString()) || (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
```